# Nested list content from JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have a nested unordered list and I want to get the content dynamically from a JSON file and not written in HTML. For this I know that I need some script but I don't know exactly.

I have structured the current list in HTML and the JSON file at **[Punkler](http://plnkr.co/edit/zLyBFR360pk5p2ieeIvw?p=preview)** just missing the script.

***HTML...***

```
<ul>
    <!-- ARIZONA -->
    <li>
        <p>Arizona</p>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>Phoenix</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Store 1</h1>
                        <p>Store 1 Address</p>
                        <p>Phoenix - AZ</p>
                        <a href="http://store_1_address.com/">View Map</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Store 2</h1>
                        <p>Store 2 Address</p>
                        <p>Phoenix - AZ</p>
                        <a href="http://store_2_address.com/">View Map</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Store 3</h1>
                        <p>Store 3 Address</p>
                        <p>Phoenix - AZ</p>
                        <a href="http://store_3_address.com/">View Map</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Tucson</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Store 4</h1>
                        <p>Store 4 Address</p>
                        <p>Tucson - AZ</p>
                        <a href="http://store_4_address.com/">View Map</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Store 5</h1>
                        <p>Store 5 Address</p>
                        <p>Tucson - AZ</p>
                        <a href="http://store_5_address.com/">View Map</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Store 6</h1>
                        <p>Store 6 Address</p>
                        <p>Tucson - AZ</p>
                        <a href="http://store_6_address.com/">View Map</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <!-- CALIFORNIA -->
    <li>
        <p>California</p>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>Los Angeles</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Store 7</h1>
                        <p>Store 7 Address</p>
                        <p>Los Angeles - CA</p>
                        <a href="http://store_7_address.com/">View Map</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Store 8</h1>
                        <p>Store 8 Address</p>
                        <p>Los Angeles - CA</p>
                        <a href="http://store_8_address.com/">View Map</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Store 9</h1>
                        <p>Store 9 Address</p>
                        <p>Los Angeles - CA</p>
                        <a href="http://store_9_address.com/">View Map</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>San Francisco</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Store 10</h1>
                        <p>Store 10 Address</p>
                        <p>San Francisco - CA</p>
                        <a href="http://store_10_address.com/">View Map</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Store 11</h1>
                        <p>Store 11 Address</p>
                        <p>San Francisco - CA</p>
                        <a href="http://store_11_address.com/">View Map</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Store 12</h1>
                        <p>Store 12 Address</p>
                        <p>San Francisco - CA</p>
                        <a href="http://store_12_address.com/">View Map</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <!-- TEXAS -->
    <li>
        <p>Texas</p>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>Austin</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Store 13</h1>
                        <p>Store 13 Address</p>
                        <p>Austin - TX</p>
                        <a href="http://store_13_address.com/">View Map</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Store 14</h1>
                        <p>Store 14 Address</p>
                        <p>Austin - TX</p>
                        <a href="http://store_14_address.com/">View Map</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Store 15</h1>
                        <p>Store 15 Address</p>
                        <p>Austin - TX</p>
                        <a href="http://store_15_address.com/">View Map</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Houston</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Store 16</h1>
                        <p>Store 16 Address</p>
                        <p>Houston - TX</p>
                        <a href="http://store_16_address.com/">View Map</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Store 17</h1>
                        <p>Store 17 Address</p>
                        <p>Houston - TX</p>
                        <a href="http://store_17_address.com/">View Map</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h1>Store 18</h1>
                        <p>Store 18 Address</p>
                        <p>Houston - TX</p>
                        <a href="http://store_18_address.com/">View Map</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

***The JSON...***

```
{
    "states": [{


        "name": "Arizona",
        "state_abbreviation": "AZ",
        "city": [
            {
                "name": "Phoenix",
                "stores": [
                    { "name": "Store 1", "address": "Store 1 Address", "map": "http://store_1_address.com/" },
                    { "name": "Store 2", "address": "Store 2 Address", "map": "http://store_2_address.com/" },
                    { "name": "Store 3", "address": "Store 3 Address", "map": "http://store_3_address.com/" }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Tucson",
                "stores": [
                    { "name": "Store 4", "address": "Store 4 Address", "map": "http://store_4_address.com/" },
                    { "name": "Store 5", "address": "Store 5 Address", "map": "http://store_5_address.com/" },
                    { "name": "Store 6", "address": "Store 6 Address", "map": "http://store_6_address.com/" }
                ]
            }
        ],


        "name": "California",
        "state_abbreviation": "CA",
        "city": [
            {
                "name": "Los Angeles",
                "stores": [
                    { "name": "Store 7", "address": "Store 7 Address", "map": "http://store_7_address.com/" },
                    { "name": "Store 8", "address": "Store 8 Address", "map": "http://store_8_address.com/" },
                    { "name": "Store 9", "address": "Store 9 Address", "map": "http://store_9_address.com/" }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "San Francisco",
                "stores": [
                    { "name": "Store 10", "address": "Store 10 Address", "map": "http://store_10_address.com/" },
                    { "name": "Store 11", "address": "Store 11 Address", "map": "http://store_11_address.com/" },
                    { "name": "Store 12", "address": "Store 12 Address", "map": "http://store_12_address.com/" }
                ]
            }
        ],


        "name": "Texas",
        "state_abbreviation": "TX",
        "city": [
            {
                "name": "Austin",
                "stores": [
                    { "name": "Store 13", "address": "Store 13 Address", "map": "http://store_13_address.com/" },
                    { "name": "Store 14", "address": "Store 14 Address", "map": "http://store_14_address.com/" },
                    { "name": "Store 15", "address": "Store 15 Address", "map": "http://store_15_address.com/" }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Houston",
                "stores": [
                    { "name": "Store 16", "address": "Store 16 Address", "map": "http://store_16_address.com/" },
                    { "name": "Store 17", "address": "Store 17 Address", "map": "http://store_17_address.com/" },
                    { "name": "Store 18", "address": "Store 18 Address", "map": "http://store_18_address.com/" }
                ]
            }
        ]

    }]
}
```

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: It is just a couple of loops

Comment: Yes, I know @epascarello! But I don't know how to do this. ;(

Comment: But, before you seek for help. You have to check the code you offer is correct. The Json you give is not in right format. You can go to w3school to study about dom manipulation, including creating elements and so on..

Comment: Thank you for the warning, @JoseMar! I think it's correct know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plunker, you mentioned json is not a valid json format. First resolve those JSON errors and try below code:

```
var states = json.states;
var tempHtml = '<ul>';

for(state in states){
    tempHtml += "<li><p>"+state.name+"</p><ul>";
    for(city in state.city){
        tempHtml += "<li><p>"+city.name+"</p><ul>";

        for(store in city.stores){
            tempHtml += "<li><h1>"+store.name+"</h1><p>"+store.address+"</p><a href='"+store.map+"'>view map</a></li>";

        }
        tempHtml += "</ul></li>";
    }
    tempHtml += "</ul></li>";

}
tempHtml += "</ul>";


$('#divid').html(tempHtml);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Aravinder! I have uptated the Plunker with your script and fixed the json errors but something is wrong yet :(

Comment: I think it is working in plunker. What issue your are phasing right now?

Comment: I saw one issue related to view map link and update above script.

Comment: I have fixed in plunker, @aravinder. Thank you for help me.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to loop. Build up a string. Basic idea for looping.

```
var states = yourJSON.states;
states.forEach( function (state) {
   console.log("\t" + state.name);
   var cities = state.city;
   cities.forEach( function (city) {
       console.log("\t\t" + city.name);
       var stores = city.stores;
       stores.forEach( function (store) {
           console.log("\t\t\t" + store.name);
       });
   });
});
```